# Angular ControlValueAccessor how to transfer the invalid status?

Tags: angular, controlvalueaccessor

I have created a custom input with `ControlValueAccessor` I can use it in formControl and it works fine. Now I would like to know when the form control is considered invalid to display a red border on the input inside my custom component.

Here is my custom input:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: InputComponent,
    },
  ],
})
export class InputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  group = new FormGroup({
    input: new FormControl(''),
  });
  touched: boolean = false;

  // The id used for the html
  id!: number;

  // The label of the html input
  @Input() label: string = '';
  @Input() type: string = 'text';

  // The method called when the input is touched
  onTouched = () => {};

  constructor() {
    this.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  }
  /**
   * The setter of the input value
   * @param value
   */
  writeValue(value: string): void {
    this.input.setValue(value);
  }

  /**
   * Function to subscribe to changes
   * @param fn
   */
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.input.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      fn(value);
    });
  }
  /**
   * Function to subscribe when the input is touched
   * @param fn
   */
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  /**
   * fucntion called to define the input as touched
   */
  markAsTouched() {
    if (!this.touched) {
      this.onTouched();
      this.touched = true;
    }
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param isDisabled
   */
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    if (isDisabled) {
      this.input.disable();
    } else {
      this.input.enable();
    }
  }

  get input() {
    return this.group.get('input') as FormControl;
  }
}
```

Then I can use it like that.

```html
<app-input
  formControlName="email"
  label="Email"
></app-input>
```

If my email form control is invalid (because it's not a valid email for example), then there is some class added on my component inside the DOM.
[image]

Is there a way to get the validity status inside the TS component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of providing your value accessor in the decorator with the `providers` property, use this :

```js
constructor(
  @Optional() @Self() private ngControl: NgControl
) {
  // ...
  if (this.ngControl) this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
}
```

It does the same thing. But what it does MORE, in your case, is to give you access to the native form control with `this.ngControl.control`.

This means you can get the status of the control at any given point, for instance, you can make this :

```
get status() {
  return this.ngControl.control.status; // "INVALID", "VALID", "PENDING"
}
```

Comment: It worked, I only had to change your `@Self` by `@Self()`. Maybe you should edit you answer to add `()`.

Comment: Yep sorry, thanks for the feddback !

Answer (score 0):

you can inject the `Injector` like this:

```
export class InputComponent implements OnInit , ControlValueAccessor {

  _control!: NgControl;

  constructor(@Inject(INJECTOR) private injector: Injector) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._control = this.injector.get(NgControl);
}
```

and then you can access all control methods - for example:

```
  get isError() {
    return this._control.control?.invalid;
  }
```