# How can I check the validation in my formGroup when i use ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I have the following code in my `app.component` which is the parent

**ts**

```
 public databaseForm = new FormGroup({
   test: new FormControl([])
 });
```

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="databaseForm">
  <add-code-description formControlName="test"></add-code-description>
</form>
```

In my add code description component I have another group

```
<form [formGroup]="childGroup">
    <div formArrayName="linkTypeCodeDescription"
        *ngFor="let linkType of getLinkTypeCodeDescriptionControls(); let linkTypeCodeDescriptionIndex = index">
        <div formGroupName="{{ linkTypeCodeDescriptionIndex }}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <input formControlName="code"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <button (click)="checkChildForm()">Check child form</button>
</form>
```

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, NgControl, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { BaseControlValueAccessor } from 'xcomponent-angular/commons/classes/base-control-value-accessor';

@Component({
    selector: 'xecm-add-code-description',
    templateUrl: './add-code-description.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add-code-description.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: AddCodeDescriptionComponent,
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class AddCodeDescriptionComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

    @Input() public formControlName: string;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        
    }

    writeValue(obj: any): void {
        // throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        // throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        // throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        // throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }


    public childGroup = new FormGroup({
        linkTypeCodeDescription: this.fb.array([
            this.fb.group({
                code: ['', [Validators.required]],
            }),
            this.fb.group({
                code: ['', [Validators.required]],
            })
        ])
    })

    public getLinkTypeCodeDescriptionControls() {
        return (this.childGroup.get('linkTypeCodeDescription') as FormArray).controls;
    }

  checkChildForm() {
        console.log(this.childGroup);
    }
}
```

So now when the page loads I have two input codes which are required.
When i type something in the input fields and i click on Check child form i can see that
the `group` form is valid because two inputs have values.If i don't put anything in the inputs the `group` form will be INVALID.

The problem is that in the parent form the `database` form is always valid - so when some of the code inputs does not have value then the database form is still VALID.

How can i 'connect`my parent form with my child form where i will get the values dynamically thrpugh control value accessor and the`database` form will know about that changes

I have seen videos where they use control value accessor but for one input.
What if i have anther input where it's value will be connected with let's say codeName in the whole `group` so if i have codeName formGroup in my child form.

How can i attach all this values dynamically with control value accessor ?

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73825575/14598976 . in this way you can get the controller from the parent with its validation method

Comment: @EliPorush thanks for your response. My question is how can i notify the parent that my child form is invalid ?

Comment: @EliPorush what you posted is - how to know that the formControl is invalid in the child form which is okay, but i need to transer that somehow to the 'test' formGroup in the `databaseForm` group

Answer (score 0):

Do not declare your control value accessor like this.

Instead, use this :

```js
  constructor(
    @Optional() @Self() private ngControl: NgControl
  ) {
    if(this.ngControl) this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
  }
```

and remove the `providers` array from your decorator.

Now, you can access your status with this :

```js
this.ngControl.control.status;
this.ngControl.control.valid;
this.ngControl.control.invalid;
this.ngControl.control.pending;
```

Comment: thank you for your response. But how can i notify the parent formGroup `database` form that the child form is not valid ?

Comment: NgControl.control.parent holds a reference to the parent.